# Windows Remote Desktop Client fails to connect with error code 0x4

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

When I connect to my Windows 10 machine from my Mac via Microsoft Remote Desktop client v10 or from Windows I'm getting an error:
Your session ended because of an error. If this keeps happening, contact your network administrator for assistance.
Error code: 0x4

Comment: duplicating the "bad connection" works sometimes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I reported this issue to MS via their Report Issue form on Mac Remote Desktop client and got the following response:

Set this key to a high value, like 10,000
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server

MaxOutstandingConnections

DWORD

Once I followed these recommendations the problem stopped.

Comment: This looked like the problem for me.  Server wouldn't let me connect via RDC, error disconnect 4.  Server was up and operational other than that.  I was locked out of remotely managing it.  Thankfully I had IPMI access to the server over the datacenter VPN.  Others, may not be so lucky..

Comment: For me, ended up that I was inadvertently running TripMode which was blocking internet for RDC. Either disabling TripMode or adding Microsoft Remote Desktop to the allowed apps did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Definitely, a Microsoft issue with RDPv10. Got same issue. Thanks for recommendation shared. Also, reboot of the remote machine helps.

Comment: Yes, reboot helps, but in my case it was quite inconvenient as I didn't have direct access to this machine, so each reboot caused me huge loss of time.